# What is better to use for running function after some time?

Tags: go, timer

What is better to use? time.AfterFunc or goroutine with sleep?

```golang
time.AfterFunc(d, func() {
  // things
})
```

```golang
go func() {
  time.Sleep(d)
  // things
}()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most computer science questions - the answer depends on the usage. Both your choices will create a goroutine. Having said that, I'd avoid `time.Sleep()` as it's uninterruptible.

Looking at a contrived polling service example:

```
func poller(ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    for {
        if err = pollRecords(ctx); err != nil {
            return
        }
        time.Sleep(1*time.Hour) // <- poll interval cannot be interrupted
    }
}
```

this function may be running for up to an hour, even after the context has been canceled, because of the uninterruptible nature of `time.Sleep`.

To fix, one can use the channel based `time.After()`:

```
// time.Sleep(1*time.Hour)

select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    return ctx.Err() // cancelling the context interrupts the time.After
case <-time.After(1*time.Hour):
}
```

---

Note [time.AfterFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/time#AfterFunc) can be canceled - but you need to capture the returned `time.TImer`:

```
t := time.AfterFunc(d, func() {
  // things
})

// ...

t.Stop() // will stop the function firing - if one decides to do so
```

Comment: Okay, thank you.